# Heap Corruption Detected : after Normal block(#82) in c Stack

Tags: c, stack

I am trying to remove top element from the stack. I am trying to free the temp which is the top element.

```
int pop(node** root) {
    if (!IsEmpty(*root)) {
        return -1;
    }
    node* temp = (*root);
    (*root) = (*root)->next;
    int popped = temp->data;
    free(temp); // Getting Error
    return popped;
}
```

Comment: Generally heap corruption is detected some time after it has happened, so this code might be fine but other code you haven't shown is the actual problem. Can you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: can you please post the whole file so someone can compile/run/debug it for you?